# Jinja2 for word templating

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine, docx

I would like to use jinja2 for word templating like mentioned is [this](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2012/07/04/document-automation.html) short article. The problem I'm facing is as follows, if I put `{{title}}` in my word-file the resulting xml can look like this:

```
<w:r><w:t>{{</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/><w:r><w:t>title</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/><w:r><w:t>}}</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

so it is impossible for jinja to replace this accordingly. Is there a possibility to prevent word from splitting `{{title}}` in separate text elements? (if I copy from a text-editor it works fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue that is in word, relating to the proofErr tag.

You have two solutions:

- If you want to stick with Jinja2, you should always write your tags in one stroke. Eg, never hit backspace or edit a tag. You can also copy/paste it from an other editor.
- I wrote a library, [Docxtemplater](https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater) that works even if the text-elements are splitted, eg it would replace:

  ```
  <w:r>
   <w:t>
     {{
   </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
   <w:r>
    <w:t>title</w:t>
   </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
   <w:r>
    <w:t>}}</w:t>
   </w:r>
  ```

  by:

  ```
  <w:r>
    <w:t>
      Your title
    </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:t></w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:t></w:t>
  </w:r>
  ```

Docxtemplater can be programmed over a CLI or in JS Browser/Node.JS

Answer (score 14):

https://pypi.org/project/docxtpl/ is also a good alternative.

It extends python-docx, and allows you to just drop in Jinja2 tags wherever you want in an existing `.docx` document, rather than templating from scratch.

Example:

```
pip install docxtpl
```

Usage:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("my_word_template.docx")
context = { 'company_name' : "Dr. Stubbs Orthopedics and Prosthetics" }
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

If your template `my_word_template.docx` file looks like this:

[[image: A .docx file with tags put in it[1]]

Then your `generated_doc.docx` will look like this:

[image: A .docx file generated using this leedle program]

Relatively simple, right?