# How do I generate multiple docx files using python's docxtpl package, thus preserve docx formatting?

Tags: python, jinja2, docx, template-engine, python-docx

I am working on a process to automate generation of offer letters for candidates. The candidate information is in Excel and contains standard information needed for offer letter generation such as candidate name, date of joining, location, job title, CTC etc.

Is there a way to generate multiple offer letters (output file name _.docx) while preserving the formatting of the docx template?

Using Stackoverflow's help, I was able to utilize python-docx package and generate multiple offer letters. Thus approach however strips all the formatting from the offer letter.

```
import os
from pandas import *
import datetime
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("\\template\\offer_letter_template.docx")
xls = ExcelFile("\\data\\candidate_data.xlsx")
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print (df.to_json(orient='records'))
```

```
Output:
[{"offer_letter_date":"July 27, 2019","candidate_name":"John Wick","candidate_email":"john.wick@gmail.com","candidate_location":"NYC","candidate_job_title":"Business Development Executive","candidate_ctc":283000},{"offer_letter_date":"July 17, 2019","candidate_name":"Jane Doe","candidate_email":"jane.doe@gmail.com","candidate_location":"NYC","candidate_job_title":"Business Development Executive","candidate_ctc":290000}]
```

```
context = df.to_json(orient='records')
doc.render(context)
```

I am struggling with creating a loop around `context` so that candidate information is saved in respective file rather than one file itself. Can someone please help?

[Jinja2 for word templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488090/jinja2-for-word-templating) was really helpful but I could not replicate it with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create multiple `docx` files, unfortunately nobody said in the `docxtpl` documentation that once you load the template, replacements are done in-place, thus preventing any further context replacements.

A workaround which you may like would be reopening the file at every iteration.

Something like:

```
context=df.to_json(orient='records')
for i in len(context):
    doc = DocxTemplate("\\template\\offer_letter_template.docx")
    template.render(context[i])
    template.save("docs-folder\\%s%(context[i][candidate_name]))
```

^Might need some revision, but you get the point.